# Magit : how to see log between 2 points

Tags: git, emacs, emacs24, magit

I would like to know how I can see the result of command like `git log ..some-branch` in magit ?

From the [doc](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/magit.html#History) :

> Giving a prefix argument to l will ask for the starting and end point of the history. This can be used to show the commits that are in one branch, but not in another, for example. The start point can also be a range of revisions “r1..r2”. In that case “r1” is used as the start and “r2” as the end point of the history.

But I do not understand how I can give this prefix argument ? Which key sequence I should use ?

Comment: The doc you refer to is old, more recent information on magit is available at: http://magit.github.com/magit/

Comment: You are right but the doc I refer is the first result when searching "magit manual" in google.. weird :(

Comment: I know, I should try to do something about it....

Comment: I wrote to philjackson which is holding this doc asking him if he can do something (remove doc or warn user that it is outdated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prefix argument is given with <kbd>C-u</kbd>. However, that doesn't seem to work with my magit. To get a ranged log, I press "l" then tab over to "Ranged short" and press enter.

Comment: I think `C-u` is not working because of the interactive params you got when you press `l`

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of magit (`2.11.0` as of writing this) log ranges can be displayed using <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> ("log other") and then entering the commit range (ex: `HEAD~5..HEAD`).

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>rl</kbd> works for me: it prompts for the two refs which will define the range.

Comment: Yes it works but the `C-u` is useless, I have the same result without it.

Comment: Ah right. The definition of the `magit-log` command contains code which should prompt for the ref range when given a prefix arg, but it doesn't seem to do anything; it might be worth filing a bug report, because (at the very least) the docs you linked to are outdated.